# Why .php pages is shown as text?

Tags: php, centos, centos7

I just installed httpd and PHP 7.2.10 on my server and all the PHP files are shown as plain text my server is working on CentOS 7.

I Added the following lines to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php3
```

And for sure restarted the httpd but didn't work yet.
Am I missing something?!

Answer (score 1):

You would also need to

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/mod_php.so
```

Comment: Where do i need to add this line?

Comment: httpd.conf - look to see if other modules are loaded.

Comment: when I added it I got this error "
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
"

Comment: You will have to locate the module. Should be here - LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

Comment: Thanks anyway I didn't find it but reinstalling PHP from EPEL fixed the problem :)

Comment: `LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so` from [IUS repo](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-x86_64/mod_php74-7.4.30-1.el7.ius.x86_64.rpm.html).